# Finding duplicate files using bash script

Tags: bash, hard-link, deduplication

How do you write a bash one-liner that will find binary files with identical contents, permissions, and owner on the same ext4 file-system, from the current working directory recursively, and replace all files with older access times with hard links to the latest accessed file and report saved disk space in kibibytes?

What I achieved until now is not fully sufficient for the requirements of the objective.

```
#! /bin/sh
fdupes -r -p -o 'time' . | xargs file -i | grep binary | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{print substr($0,3)}' | sed 's/.\{1\}$//' | xargs rdfind -makehardlinks true
```

Comment: What is missing from your current solution until all your requirements are completed?

Comment: hard links of files are not created based on the owner in rdfind.

Comment: There is the `hardlink` command for this purpose. Read `man hardlink`.

Comment: @waltinator But hardlink, don't have the features that this problem requires.

Comment: While `fdupes` is returning groups of files (in paragraph mode or using -1 in a line), you lose this grouping after the first following command, and you need it for any processing later, where will you point a hard link? To the first or last, according to your time order, of that files group. Also filenames should be preserved.

Comment: @thanasisp you are correct. So can you help me with how to approach the problem?

Comment: `hardlink` seems a good choice. What part of your requirements do you think is breaking? Binary files can be filtered, it can take only the binary files from a find as arguments, instead of a directory. It reports saved disk. For the times, I am not sure what's the meaning for this, they are identical files.

Comment: @thanasisp files with identical contents, permissions, and the owner and replace all files with older access times with hard links to the latest accessed file and report saved disk space in kibibytes. Will that be done using hardlink? Also have seen the man page it is referring that it will take directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hardlink` may not satisfy all requirements for this, but it can be used for what it is, to make the hardlinks. It can accept file arguments, not only directories, and it seems it is always linking a group of identical files to the first in order. Also it will ignore zero size files.

`fdupes` selects exactly what needed, but does not output real file arguments but a paragraph-mode output, with groups of identical files, every group is ended with an empty line.

So in order to be sure that the exact selections of `fdupes` will be hardlinked, we have to call `hardlink` separately once per paragraph. To avoid the case where two pairs of the same identicals exists for different owners or with different permissions. And of course files have to be filtered for binaries.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
unset arr i
while IFS= read -r f; do

    # move file to array if binary
    if file -i "$f" | grep -q "charset=binary"; then
        arr[++i]="$f"
    fi
    
    # if end of paragraph and array has files, hardlink and unset array
    if [[ "$f" == "" && "${arr[@]}" ]]; then
        printf "\n => Hardlink for %d files:\n" "$i"
        hardlink -n -c -vv "${arr[@]}"
        unset arr i
    fi

done < <(fdupes -rpio time .)
```

`hardlink` with `-n` parameter simulates and does not write anything, so test the above as is and remove `-n` later.

Also filenames with newlines are not handled, testing with whitespaces seems ok.

Comment: But when you feed the files to hardlink you cannot differentiate files from different users.

Comment: The use case is fileA and fileB are identical in regards to content, permission and owner is USER1 with fileA's accessed time is the latest. Another fileC and fileD are identical in regards to content, permission, and owner is USER2 with fileD's accessed time is the latest. Then fileB will be replaced with fileA's hardlink and fileC with be replaced by fileD's hardlink.

Comment: Thank you a lot the script above does most of the job. But will be considered a one-liner bash script and how we can display the size saved in kibibytes?

Comment: If this answer helps you, you may also check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). The output also has a very good -vv reporting that can be parsed, stored, modified etc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the desired result. Thanks to @thanasisp. For this, you need two programs fdupes and rdfind.

```
#!/bin/bash
unset arr i; while IFS= read -r f; do if file -i "$f" | grep -q "charset=binary"; then arr[++i]="$f"; fi; if [[ "$f" == "" && "${arr[@]}" ]]; then printf "\n => Hardlink for %d files:\n" "$i";rdfind -makehardlinks true "${arr[@]}" | grep "Total size is" | grep -P "[0-9]+" -o  | head -1 | awk -v count="$i" '{print $1/count;}' | awk '{printf("%s kibibytes saved.\n",$1/1024)}'; unset arr i; fi; done < <(fdupes -rpio time .)
```